# ERROR [TypeError: Network request failed]

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo, react-native-flatlist

I am getting the  ERROR:

> [TypeError: Network request failed]

in my react native expo app js file for API Integration. The same API using in my react js web development it works well. But It didn't work in  my react native expo mobile app.

Comment: Don't use Local host address. Using public IPv4 address. We are using local host address in react js web development. React native work on our IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reference `localhost` from your app - instead during local development you can directly specify the IP address. Luckily you can get this at runtime using `expo-constants`.

```
import Constants from "expo-constants";

const { manifest } = Constants;

const uri = `http://${manifest.debuggerHost.split(':').shift()}:3000`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Local host address. Using public IPv4 address.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).